# Aura handler is calling his action twice

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, aura-handler, event-handler

```
<aura:handler event="c:ResultApplicationEvent"  action="{!c.onResultHandler}" />
```

This is an aura Handler. this is the only handler present in my project which is handling the ResultApplicationEvent (Application Event) .

Here is the code where i'm firing the Event. I have checked it is firing just once.

```
const appEvent = $A.get('e.c:ResultApplicationEvent');
appEvent.setParams({result : resultValue});
appEvent.fire();
```

But my handler is calling onResultHandler Twice.
Can anyone telp me how to solve his problem

I have added alert inside the function which is firing the event.

```
    fireResultEvent : function(resultValue){
    alert("firing The Result Application Event from BoarHelper and result is 
    :"+resultValue);
    const appEvent = $A.get('e.c:ResultApplicationEvent');
    appEvent.setParams({result : resultValue});
    appEvent.fire();
    }
```

In this function alert is executed once.

On the handler Function I also added an alert.

```
    onResultHandler: function(component, event, helper){
    alert("wao working onResult Handler");
    }
```

But this alert is executing twice.

Comment: How have you verified the event is only being called once? How do you know the handler is called twice. Each event should be handled once per handler. Do you have the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en)? Have you checked the number of events and match them up to what you're seeing?

Comment: I have edit may question again and explained how with the help of alert I have confirm that event is firing once. but handlerMethod is calling twice. plz check it one more time. And I don't have salesforce Lightining Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

For an Application Event, it will be delivered just once to every component that has a registered listener for each appropriate phase, as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_propagation.htm). This means that if you have two *instances* (unique copies of your component) in the page, both will receive the event. It may be that you meant to use a Component Event instead, which can only go directly up or down a component hierarchy, or you may have wanted to capture the event to a non-default component root, which you can do by calling `event.stopPropagation()` during the capture or bubble phases.

To illustrate, if you code looks like:

```
<c:toplevel>
  <c:parent>
   <c:child>
  </c:parent>
  <c:parent>
   <c:child>
  </c:parent>
</c:toplevel>
```

If the first `c:parent` fires an Application Event, both `c:child` components would receive the event. If you want to stop that from happening, add a handler in `c:parent` to stop the propagation:

```
<aura:handler event="c:ResultApplicationEvent" action="{!c.containAppEvent}" phase="capture" includeFacets="true" />
```

...

```
 containAppEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
   event.stopPropagation();
 }
```

At this point, the Application Event would be contained just inside the `c:parent` that fired off the event, so then only `c:child` in that parent would receive it.